# How save edit form in multilanguage project

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-parler

I'm studying Django from the book Django 2 by Examples.
I'm trying to improve a project which starts in chapter 10. Now, I'm trying to add multilingualism with the help of "django-parler".
In general I did it, but it seems to me that there are better ways.
Views are implemented as classes that are inherited from mixins. If a language other than the default language is selected on the page, the form still comes with the value of laguage_code field equal to default.
I tried unsuccessfully to change this field in the form_valid method. The form was still saved with the default language.
The only option that works for me is this, by it looks like kludge:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    language = translation.get_language()
    _course = form.save(commit=False)

    try:
        course = Course.objects.get(pk=_course.id)
    except Course.DoesNotExist:
        course = Course()
        course.owner = self.request.user
    course.set_current_language(language)

    cd = form.cleaned_data
    course.subject = cd['subject']
    course.title = cd['title']
    course.slug = cd['slug']
    course.overview = cd['overview']
    course.save()
    return redirect(reverse('courses:manage_list'))
```

Maybe someone knows a more elegant way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you have a class based Django `FormView` with `ModelFormMixin`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.obj = form.save()  # you dont need it in UpdateView
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

By the way.

`Django-Parler` or `Django-HVAD` are already died projects.
You can use django-modelTranslation. Or my project Django-TOF v.2.

Of course django 2 is already very old project.  Django 4.1 is much much better.

In my opinion the best book about Django - Django Design Patterns and Best Practices. Last version. it is more Django-ish than "2 scope" or "Django 2 by Example"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's works, but it didn't solve the problem. The form is still saved in the default language.
I was forced to add to the method two lines: `self.object.owner = self.request.user` and `self.object.save()`, replacing at the same time `self.object = form.save()` to `self.object = form.save(commit=False)`.